# How open multiple encrypted PDF and save without password in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pikepdf

I am a newbee just started my first language as Python.

I am trying to write code to open multiple encrypted pdf files and save them without password.

All files are in a folder, I have a csv file `filePassword.csv` with columns `filename` and `password`.

But my code is not working. Please guide me on how to solve this error.

```
import pikepdf as pdf
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filePassword.csv')
filename, password = df['filename'], df['password']
for file in filename:
    for code in password:
        file1 = pdf.open(file,code)
        file1.save('1_'+filename)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the dataframe `df` using `iterrows()` and then access `filename` and `password` in following way. There is no need of nested loops.

```
import pikepdf as pdf
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filePassword.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    file1 = pdf.open(row['filename'], row['password'])
    file1.save('1_'+row['filename'])
```

Comment: This is working perfectly thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file` instead of `filename`:

```
import pikepdf as pdf
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filePassword.csv')
for file in df['filename']:
    for code in df['password']:
        file1 = pdf.open(file,code)
        file1.save('1_' + file)
```

Comment: hi, code is working only for first file in the list but after that got error "PasswordError: 40094489-01122020.pdf: invalid password" and "40094489-01122020.pdf" is the first file in the list